# Android : read from a buffer until a specific char or string is recieved

Tags: java, android

I am new to this site as well as android. I trying to code for a TCP client. I can send data and receive as well. I want to read from the in buffer, I can use `in.readLine();` but this will just read until a new line. I will read until I receive `!!` or the Buffer is empty or the data in the received response is more than 160 chars.

MY current code is

```
bSend.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                String outMsg = textField.getText().toString().trim();
                out.write(outMsg);
                out.flush();
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                mstr=in.readLine();
                tv.setText(mstr);
                Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + mstr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            finally{

            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: You can `split()` the line you read to check for `!!`. If you find it, the last part of the response will be in the first part of the string, and the next message(assuming there is one) will be in the latter part.

Comment: @Geobits do u mean that I will read using `.readLine`? in that case if there is no  '\n' in the response how will I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use .read() instead of .readLine().

```
String total = "";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));;
while (total.length() < 160 && total.endsWith("!!") == false){ // if the string is less then 160 chars long and not ending with !!
    int c = in.read(); // read next char in buffer
    if(c == -1) break; // in.read() return -1 if the end of the buffer was reached
    total += (char)c; // add char to string
}
in.close();
```