# Android TCP Server only displays messages from Python Client after Client is closed

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, android-studio

I am using some sample code, that allows me to send a message from a Python client to an Android server (TCP). But the message only gets displayed on the Android Emulator after the client is closed.

I am perhaps missing some basic understanding behind tcp sockets (first time use and implementation).

My main intention is to have buttons in the Android App that send a different message to the Python client on a separate Linux system when clicked upon, and the Python client, after getting that message, sends back an acknowledgment.

Following is my code

**Server.java**

```
package test.server2;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Server {
    MainActivity activity;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    String message = "";
    static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;

    public Server(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
        socketServerThread.start();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return socketServerPORT;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // create ServerSocket using specified port
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

                while (true) {
                    // block the call until connection is created and return
                    // Socket object
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    count++;


                    InputStream message2 = socket.getInputStream();
                    final String messageReceived = convertToString(message2);

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            activity.msg.setText(messageReceived);
                        }
                    });


                    //SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread =
                      //      new SocketServerReplyThread(socket, count);
                    //socketServerReplyThread.run();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    activity.msg.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

        private Socket hostThreadSocket;
        int cnt;

        SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
            hostThreadSocket = socket;
            cnt = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream outputStream;
            String msgReply = "Hello from Server, you are #" + cnt;

            try {
                outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
                printStream.print(msgReply);
                printStream.close();

                message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        activity.msg.setText(message);
                    }
                });


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    activity.msg.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    private String convertToString(InputStream message) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(message));
        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                //stringbuilder.append(line).append('\n');
                stringbuilder.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                message.close();
                //reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return stringbuilder.toString();
    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress
                            .nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "Server running at : "
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return ip;
    }
}
```

I have the calls to SocketServerReplyThread and related commented out, because that led to an error. Commenting that out leads to receiving the message from the Python Client but it only gets displayed on the Android Emulator after the client socket is closed. I want it to be continuous so that, whenever the client sends a message (And the android server is listening) the message gets printed.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package test2.server;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Server server;
    TextView infoip, msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();


            }
        });

        infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        server = new Server(this);
        infoip.setText(server.getIpAddress() + ":" + server.getPort());

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        server.onDestroy();


    }
}
```

**Python client**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "127.0.0.1" 
port = 4534
s.connect((host, port))


s.send("Thank you for connecting" + '\n')
time.sleep(10) #added to check if it gets displayed before closing or not
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets block by default.  So when you call readline, it will never return null until the socket is closed. As coded, your code will wait until all the data is read from the client and the client closes the connection, then you turn it into 1 big string and return it from convertToString.  You need to rearchitect so that you handle the result of each readline call and display it, not treat everything as 1 giant string.

Comment: Would you recommend using read() instead of readline() somehow like the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520206/android-read-from-a-buffer-until-a-specific-char-or-string-is-recieved ?

Comment: The code in the link I provided in the above comment is working for me at the moment. Thanks for your suggestion regarding readline. Appreciate it a lot!