# What are the drawbacks of opening and closing a Python TCP Client socket in multiple successions?

Tags: android, python, sockets, tcp

I have an Android TCP Server and a Python TCP Client socket. I am trying to send data/messages from the Python Client to the Server, where the Android app displays it on the screen.

However, the message is displayed only **after** the Client closes. I can't seem to have the message displayed before the Client Socket is closed so that I can have multiple messages sent between the Server and Client. I asked a question for the same issue, which is still unanswered -> [Android TCP Server only displays messages from Python Client after Client is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660738/android-tcp-server-only-displays-messages-from-python-client-after-client-is-clo)

So what if I attempt to have the Client Socket Open and Close multiple times just for the sake of sending and receiving data? What are the drawbacks of doing this over a wifi network?

P.S. - If someone is willing to offer more help - I am trying to have buttons on the Android App which upon being pressed/clicked send a individual messages (always the same) to the Client, and after each message the Client sends an acknowledgment message back. Any design tips to implement this for a complete newbie who is trying to have an app communicate with a robot would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If you're not recieving the data until closed, you're doing something wrong and should fix it.  Continually opening and closing a connection, in addition to being an ugly hack, will result in worse performance due to conneciton handshakes taking multiple trips and due to anti-congestion code in the TCP protocol not optimizing for your actual conneciton speed well.

Comment: @GabeSechan - Could you help point out whatever I am doing wrong? The linked question has the code I am referring to. Would appreciate your help. And thanks for pointing out the problem with the continuous opening and closing as well!