# Android handler bufferedreader.read() closes the app when recieving data

Tags: android, python, sockets, android-studio, socket.io

hi im new in android programming and in sockets im trying to recieve a data from the client, when i use .readline() my textview only updates when i close the client program in python so i use .read() the app closes what could be the problem?

this is the code:

```
        class Mythread implements Runnable{



    Handler h = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Socket s;
        ServerSocket ss;
        InputStreamReader ist;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(21600);
            s = ss.accept();
            ist = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(ist);
            while (true){

                final String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                Log.d("message", "message: " + message);

                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ballscollect.setText(message);

                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

this is my python client code where every time the switch is clicked it will send a output string to the app:

```
 import socket
from nanpy import (ArduinoApi, SerialManager)
import time
import thread

import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
import math

lcd_rs        = 26  
lcd_en        = 19
lcd_d4        = 13
lcd_d5        = 6
lcd_d6        = 5
lcd_d7        = 11
lcd_backlight = 4

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows    = 2

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)

lcd.message ('Balls Collected')

ledpin = 13
buttonpin = 12
buttonpin1 = 2
buttonpin2 = 3
buttonstate1 = 1
buttonstate2 = 1
buttonstate3 = 1

connection = SerialManager()
a = ArduinoApi(connection = connection)

a.pinMode(ledpin, a.OUTPUT)
a.pinMode(buttonpin, a.INPUT)
a.pinMode(buttonpin1, a.INPUT)
a.pinMode(buttonpin2, a.INPUT)

host = '192.168.1.7'
port = 21600
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host,port))



def count():
    add = 0
    while True:


        buttonstate1 = a.digitalRead(buttonpin)
        buttonstate2 = a.digitalRead(buttonpin1)
        buttonstate3 = a.digitalRead(buttonpin2)

        if buttonstate1:

            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.HIGH)

        else:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.LOW)
            add += 1
            s = str(add)
            lcd.message ('\n'+s)
            sock.send(s)              #this is the output string that is sent to the app
            print ('sent')
            time.sleep (.5)

        if buttonstate2:

            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.HIGH)

        else:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.LOW)
            add += 1
            s = str(add)
            sock.send(s)       #this is the output string that is sent to the app
            lcd.message ('\n'+s)
            print ('sent')
            time.sleep (.5)


        if buttonstate3:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.HIGH)


        else:
            a.digitalWrite(ledpin, a.LOW)
            add += 1
            s = str(add)
            lcd.message ('\n'+s)
            sock.send(s)   #this is the output string that is sent to the app
            print ('sent')
            time.sleep (.5)                                             

    sock.close()


thread.start_new_thread(count, ())
```

ive got an error at logcat

```
01-30 22:39:23.437 21785-21802/com.example.mahilum.tbot D/message: message: null
01-30 22:39:23.437 21785-21802/com.example.mahilum.tbot D/message: message: null
01-30 22:39:23.437 21785-21802/com.example.mahilum.tbot D/message: message: null
01-30 22:39:23.438 21785-21802/com.example.mahilum.tbot D/message: message: null
01-30 22:39:23.438 21785-21802/com.example.mahilum.tbot D/message: message: null
01-30 22:39:23.438 21785-21802/com.example.mahilum.tbot D/message: message: null
01-30 22:39:23.438 21785-21802/com.example.mahilum.tbot D/message: message: null
```

Comment: `when i use .readline() my textview only updates when i close the program `. Well than the server will not have send a line. Only some characters. The server should send lines too. A line ends with a "\n" character.

Comment: `bufferedReader.close();` Oh oh... Put that AFTER the while loop. Its difficult reading from a stream that is already closed ;-).

Comment: im sorry sir im not very clear in my question , when i close the client program the textview only update , im going to edit my question

Comment: ohh ok sir haha

Comment: sir is it ok to just delete the bufferedReader.close();

Comment: I told you where you should put it already. If you do not want that then tell why.

Comment: i got an error: unreachable statement

Comment: Dont let us guess please. Edit your post so we can see where you have it.

Comment: ok sir its been edited

Comment: Think its because of the `while(true)`. So the compiler thinks that the loop never ends and hence following code would never be reached. Change to `while(connected)` and add a `boolean connected=true;` to the class.

Comment: `The server should send lines too.`Sorry my wrong. That should have been: The client should send lines too.

Comment: Further: after one read the server discards the just connected client and waits for another client to connect. Is this what you want?

Comment: no sir i only have one client and the client has successfully send the data but when the app receive it, it closes

Comment: What is the client sending? One character only? Or more ? Does it send a line?

Comment: `s = ss.accept();
                ist = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(ist);
   ` That should all be placed BEFORE the while loop. Please adapt your code.

Comment: `Socket s;
    ServerSocket ss;
    InputStreamReader ist;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    int message;`. Rremove that all and place them in the `run()`. And not sooner that you are gonna use them. Please adapt your code.

Comment: ok sir ,Only one character , its a counter sir

Comment: `no sir i only have one client and the client has successfully send the data`. And after that? Is the client going to send other data after a while? Does it stay connected? Or does the client close after having send one `byte` ? You should tell more about how server and client(s) communicate. There are so mant possibilities and you let us guess now.

Comment: `Only one character , its a counter sir` In one character or one byte you can only count to 255. You realise?

Comment: yes sir the client is still going to send and it will stay connected,ihave only one client,and i want to do is when the client send the data it will update my textview. the counting is already process in the client so it will only send the output.

Comment: Then adapt your code as i suggested.

Comment: `the counting is already process in the client so it will only send the output` ???? You have not reacted on a 255 limit. Or what the output would be.

Comment: im very sorry ,Sir the output is only in string so every time the client count it will send a string

Comment: Then give an example of such a string! Why do you lett us guess so much? If it is a string than make it a line an use readLine(). And adapt the code as i suggested.

Comment: sir i already edited the code that you suggest but its also the same the textview only update when i close the client programm

Comment: You did not read my comment with `BEFORE the while loop.` !?

Comment: `String message;` Also move that to the `run()`. Put it in the while loop. You only need that variable there.

Comment: You posted your python code but i do not like to dig through it. You should just care for sending a line. A string that ends on '\n'. Please just telll what you do.

Comment: sir i got an error when i move the Sting message in the run () ballscollect.setText(message); variable message is access from within class needs to be declared  final and when i edit it there is another error in  message = bufferedReader.readLine();  variable message might be asigned in loop

Comment: `String message;`. Remove that. And change `message = bufferedReader.readLine();` to `final String message = bufferedReader.readLine();`. You should only declare a variable where you need it and use it.

Comment: add += 1
s = str(add)
sock.send(s)   the variable s is what i send to the app

Comment: I cannot see if s ends on '\n'. It should as you know.

Comment: Sir the message displays in a blink and gone what could be the problem

Comment: Sir it closes the app, i edited the code the error is shown below

Comment: Ok sir i just edited it

Comment: Ok. Change the log statement to `Log.d("message", "message: " + message);`

Comment: You can also add a statement like `if ( message==null) message="omg message is null"`. Place it before the log statement.

Comment: if message==null then the client has closed the connection. This is not like you said the client would behave. Add `if (message==null) connected = false`. (So use the 'connected' variable again.

Comment: if (message == null){
                        message = "omg message is null";
                    } i got an error on message cannot assign to final variable 'message'

Comment: Yes indeed. That is impossible. I oversaw the final. Well im not going to teach you all java. Solve this problem yourself please.

Comment: Yes sir cause it only display when i close the client, its not updating while the client is sending the data

Comment: My god... Does the client send a line then???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660738/android-tcp-server-only-displays-messages-from-python-client-after-client-is-clo sir i found a same problem here but i dont know what to do

Comment: `sock.send(s)` Change to `sock.send(s + "\n")`

Comment: oh my god isr its working

Comment: thank you very much for that '\n' is the only problem

Comment: really very much thank you sir from the bottom of my heart you stayed and help me thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sock.send(s)` Change to `sock.send(s + "\n")`

And remember my first comment:

```
Well than the server will not have send a line. 
Only some characters. 
The server should send lines too. A line ends with a "\n" character.
```

Comment: i should do that from the beginning thank you very much sir :)